# How to disable /cpanel and /webmail etc

Tags: url, cpanel

What is the best and most secure way to disable `/cpanel` and `/webmail` from the end of my website's URL?

I would like to disable them so they can't be accessed that way.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your question? Why do you want this to be removed?

Comment: I would like to disable them so they can't be accessed that way

Comment: Steve, google for .htaccess (when using Apache)  -  a 'deny all' could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have not fully control on your servers I mean to the OS through SSH, according to my assumption the easiest way would be redirect those urls to your home page.  What web server do you use ? Nginx, Apache etc. ? If this is apache then what is the version ?
You can find your web server config edit section in Cpanel I'm not sure where it is.

There may be those url configs specified. The clear way would be remove them. But if you couldn't find it add one of the config according to your web sever and version

**Apache 2.2**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)/cpanel(.*)$ / [R]
RewriteRule (.*)/webmail(.*)$ / [R]
```

[Apache 2.2 Doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html)

**Apache 2.4**

```
AliasMatch "(.*)/cpanel(.*)$" "/"
AliasMatch "(.*)/webmail(.*)$" "/"
```

[Apache 2.4 Doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html)

**Nginx**

```
rewrite (.*)/cpanel(.*)$ / ;
rewrite (.*)/webmail(.*)$ / ;
```

[Nginx Doc](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/)

Comment: I have standard web hosting with HostGator, using cPanel

Comment: actually I find a hostgator video tutorial for redirect method. http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/url-redirect-how-to-create

Comment: Solved my problem. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: @SteveSmith the answer it's partial correct. On Cpanel if you make any changes on httpd.conf, this changes will lost on next Cpanel update. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107237/how-to-disable-cpanel-urls . Also you can see http://www.h3xed.com/web-development/disable-url-shortcuts-cpanel-whm-webmail-cpanel-vps